# Elasticsearch return less result than SQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

The data structure is a `Post` which has_many `Post_text`. Following a great example at https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-rails/blob/master/elasticsearch-model/examples/activerecord_associations.rb. I have defined the mapping as the following:

```
include SearchableModule
mapping do
  indexes :country
  indexes :post_texts do
    indexes :subject, type: 'string', boost: 10, analyzer: 'snowball'
    indexes :description, type: 'string', analyzer: 'snowball'
  end
end
```

And of course, in the `searchable_module.rb` I just copy what's in the example with some changes in `as_index_json()`:

```
def as_indexed_json(options={})
  self.as_json(
    include: { post_texts: { only: [:subject, :description]}
             })
end
```

And things seems ok. I have re-import the data:

```
Post.import
Post.__elasticsearch__.
```

Then I try to check the result of SQL's LIKE and Elasticsearch by:

SQL LIKE:

```
PostText.where("subject LIKE '%Testing%' OR description LIKE '%Testing%'").each do |r|
    puts r.post_id
end
```

There are 12 unique post_id with this approach.

Elasticsearch:

```
Post.search("Testing").results.count
=> 10
```

Is there anything I have missed? Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try `Post.search("Testing").total` which should return summary number of results, in case with `results.count` you just count number of returned records suppose limited per_page

Comment: `Post.search("Testing").results.total shows 12! Thank you for your help!